# differences on syncrhonized block implementations

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I would an explanation on these different implmentations:

First:

```
public void foo(Object key){
    synchronized (map.get(key)) { //-> thread can enter with different key
        int variable = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <new Random().nextInt(10); j++)
            variable+=j;
        return variable;
    }
}
```

Second:

```
public void foo(Object key){
        int variable = 0;
        synchronized (map.get(key)) {      
            for (int j = 0; j < new Random().nextInt(10); j++)
                variable+=j;
            return variable;
        }
    }
```

Third:

```
 public void foo(Object key){
    int variable = 0;
    synchronized (map.get(key)) {      
      for (int j = 0; j <new Random().nextInt(10); j++)
       variable+=j;
       lock.lock(); // class instance lock
        try{
        setTheVariable(variable) //-> Example.....
        }finally{
          lock.unlock();
        }
        return variable;
      }
   }
```

- In my opinion the first two implementations are the same, if each thread enter the `syncrhonized` `block` they share the `for loop` but they have got their own `variable` copy, is right?
- I have a doubt in the third implementation, if each thread enter the `syncrhonzized block` , after finishing only one can enter inside the `lock block` and the other have to wait. ***In this case when one thread can return*** each variable resulting of the `for loop` remains attached on his own `thread`?

thanks in advance.

Comment: you're right about the first two cases being equal, however the 3rd case is unclear what you ask about. `//do something` require both locks to be obtained (`notClassInstanceObject` and `lock`)

Comment: synchronized is used to make sure two threads don't access shared state at the same time. Except for `someLimit`, there is no shared state at all here. It's also not clear why you would need two different locks to protect the same state, in your last example.

Comment: @JBNizet in the `lock block` i have to do some things before returning, and consequently i've to protect this state for being exetuced by many threads if it's can be unclear, imagine that `notClassInstanceObject` is a object that is always different .

Comment: So when i finish, `each variable resulting of the for loop remains attached on his own thread`?

Comment: @JBNizet see updates

Comment: @YokupokuMaioku we don't have any idea what you're trying to achieve. Which shared state are you trying to protect? What is hidden under the "do something" comment. How are someLimit and notClassInstanceObject and lock defined. Without knowing these details, we can't know if your synchronization makes any sense or not.

Comment: @JBNizet see updates, i think now it's more clear.

Comment: OK, so, in the first 2 examples, there is no shared state at all. And you're always synchronizing on a new object. So this makes no sense at all. synchroniation is completely useless. In the last example, the only thing that should be synchronized, if necessary, is the `setTheVariable()` method. It seems you haven't understoof what synchronization is and why and when it's necessary.

Comment: @JBNizet  i know it makes any sense `new Object()`, but it is a placeHolder  which means an object it's different for each threads, see updates for a more cler view.

Comment: The point remains: there is no shared state accessed by the method, so synchronization is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared inside the foo() method remains attached to the individual threads,because they are local variables. Here you are declaring "j" and "variable" inside the method and those variables will remain attached to the thread executing the method.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two implementations are the same.

In your third implementation, only one thread can enter the synchronized block, irrespective of whether it is an class instance variable, so the `lock` is somehow redundant unless your `//Do Something Here` section has a compelling reason to do so.

Because all the variables involved are local variables, each thread has its own copy of these variables. The returned value of one thread will not be affected by another thread.

However, always watch out for deadlock if two locks are used in this fashion.